# NLog - Daily Log file - how to add a summary when it's triggered or new log file is created

Tags: nlog

I have the config setup for daily logging. (I assume the following is correct). How can add a 'summary' when the new log file is created. **I'd like to add a daily 'count' to the last line in the log file for the day**. Is this possible? How do I know when the new log is triggered?

```
 <variable name="logDirectory" value="C:/Logs/" />
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="ErrorLog"
            filename="${logDirectory}PDF.log"
            archiveFileName="log.{#}.log"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd" />
```

Answer (score 1):

NLog FileTarget has support for Footer-layout and Header-Layout.

If you need special statistics then you probably need to write your owned custom layout-renderer.

```
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target name="ErrorLog" xsi:type="File" 
         header="----------------- Logging started on ${longdate} ------------------"
         footer="----------------- Logging finished on ${longdate} -----------------"
         filename="${logDirectory}PDF.log"
         archiveFileName="log.{#}.log"
         archiveNumbering="Date"
         archiveEvery="Day"
         archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="ErrorLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: thx.. Where can I find info on writing my custom layout-render

Comment: @Jon here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer